# Spark read/write to Azure blob storage - IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs

Tags: azure, apache-spark, hadoop, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks

I am trying to read/write to Azure blob storage but am constantly getting the "No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs". Here is what my gradle file looks like

```
plugins {
    // Apply the scala plugin to add support for Scala
    id 'scala'
    id 'idea'
    id 'application'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()

    maven {
        url "https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/public"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Spark SQL subsumes Spark Core
    compileOnly 'org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.12:3.0.3'
    implementation group: 'org.scala-lang', name: 'scala-library', version: '2.12.1'

    implementation group: 'com.typesafe', name: 'config', version: '1.4.1'
    implementation group: 'com.microsoft.azure', name: 'azure-storage', version: '8.6.6'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-azure', version: '3.3.1'
}


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes('Main-Class': 'AppRunner')
    }
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'

    duplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
}
```

I am creating a jar file with all the required dependencies for hadoop-azure and azure-storage.

This is what my Scala file is primarily doing.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.key.<blob-name>.blob.core.windows.net", "<blob-key>")
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.azure", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")

val df = spark.read.parquet("wasbs://<container-name>@<blob-name>.blob.core.windows.net/data/")
```

My Spark setup is currently on a VM in the Azure environment where I am running Spark 3.1.2 in standalone mode.

My spark-submit command looks like

`./spark-3.1.2-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit --master "local[*]" --jars jars/hadoop-azure-3.3.1.jar,jars/azure-storage-8.6.6.jar compiled-job.jar`

I do not need to include the jars as a parameter but I included it for testing because it seems that the Spark job cannot primarily find the `wasbs` filesystem.

Here is the exception I receive when I run the jar file

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No FileSystem for scheme: wasbs
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:2660)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2703)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2685)
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this configuration: spark.conf.set("fs.wasbs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem")